# Serving log files from Spring Boot's embedded Tomcat

Tags: spring-boot, embedded-tomcat-8

I'm looking to have my log files available to an admin without needing to `ssh` to the host.

Hopefully something easy as `http://myhost:myport/logs/app.log` .

Is there any way to expose an endpoint using Spring Boot that would serve my log files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [Spring Boot Actuator](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready)

Add the following dependency to your application:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And out of the box you'll get a lot of useful endpoints including: `/logfile`

No additional configuration necessary.

Comment: Thanks! Again, with Spring Boot, it was just too easy. I had already set up actuator but didn't realize that was all that's needed, while I had spent my time trying to expose the logs as a static resource instead.

Comment: it should be `/loggers/{...}`, `/logfile` without the `/loggers/` does not work on my end.